# SQL Server : CREATE SEQUENCE - unknown object type

Tags: sql-server-2008

I encounter a problem with the following part of a query:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.sequences seq JOIN sys.schemas sch ON seq.schema_id=sch.schema_id WHERE seq.name=N'LID'  AND sch.name=N'dbo' )
   DROP SEQUENCE [dbo].[LID]
GO
```

It keeps telling me, that `sys.sequences` is an unknown object name and `seq.schema_id` cannot be resolved.

I run SQL Server Express 2008 R2.

How do I Fix this?

Comment: How to fix it? Upgrade to SQL Server **2012** - sequences are a **new feature** in the 2012 release

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sys.sequences` table is not available in sql server 2008

Sequence is introduced in sql server  from **SQL server 2012**

[Click here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff877934.aspx)

Comment: found out seconds later and forgot to close this, thank you anyway^^